# If $c$ is a positive number, $|a|<c \Leftrightarrow -c<a<c$ and $|a|>c \Leftrightarrow a<-c$ or $a>c$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

> If $c$ is a positive number, $|a|<c \Leftrightarrow -c<a<c$ and $|a|>c
>  \Leftrightarrow a<-c$ or $a>c$.

I am not sure I understand the statement. Can you explain to me why is it true?

Comment: Do you know the precise definition of $|c|$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does $-b < a < b \implies |a| < b$ (and also the converse)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051591/why-does-b-a-b-implies-a-b-and-also-the-converse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The modulus of a real number $x$ is defined as
$$\lvert x \rvert = 
\begin{cases}
x, &\text{if } x\geq 0,\\
-x, &\text{if } x<0.
\end{cases}$$
Now, you can show $\Longrightarrow$ and $\Longleftarrow$ by using a case differentiation.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Now I am trying to show $\Longrightarrow)$ $|a|<c \Rightarrow -c<a<c$. If $a \ge 0 \Rightarrow |a|=a$. Therefore, we have $a<c$. How do we show $a>-c$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova If $a\geq 0$, then $a>-c$ naturally. Now do the same for $a$ negative.

Comment: I got it. But how to show $\Longleftarrow)$ $-c<a<c \Rightarrow |a|<c$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova If $a$ is non-negative, you have to show $a < c$. If $a$ is negative, you have to show $-a < c$. This immediately follows from $-c < a < c$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see it:
\begin{align*}
|a| < c \Longleftrightarrow |a|^{2} < c^{2} \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} - c^{2} < 0 \Longleftrightarrow (a-c)(a+c) < 0 \Longleftrightarrow -c < a < c
\end{align*}